# Genetic algorithm Crossover Number of offsprings

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I am trying to understand some problem of optimization using genetic algorithms.
It sounds like this: let N be the size of initial population and C the number of offsprings. 
N=100. The probability of recombination (crossover) is "about" 50%(case a) and 60% (case b). What it is not clear is the maximum number of offsprings.

My idea: for case with 50%=> C=N/2=50 => N+C = 150 (the extended population). But this does not seem plausible, because of coputing complexity.Shouldn't it be limited to let's say ~100 individuals? Or it is okay, if it's followed by a elitism selection? So N/2 is far from the real/actual number of offsprings we can generate via crossover? If the probability of recombination would have been 60%, then I guess C would have been N*0.6, right?

Comment: There are many, many ways to do a genetic algorithm. You could have most of the initial N population survive to the next generation, or you could have far less than half of them survive, with the empty spaces filled by the results of crossover and/or mutation. It would help if you could explain in detail what is the definition of "probability of recombination" you are trying to implement.

Comment: I might have expressed myself a little bit fuzzy. The idea was: let C = N/2 be the chance(probability) of getting 2 individuals (different(like"A and B") or the same one, paired with itself like "AA")  (out of N individuals) paired in order to result a child. 2 parents -> 1 child. So, if we have N =50 parents, then C=50/2=25 children. We select 2 parents out of 50 , 25 times.

Comment: The max number of children would still be C, because you will reduce the population from (N+C) back to N(elitism selection)?

Comment: The process you have described has 100% probability to choose exactly N/2 pairs to cross over. A 50% probability implies at some point in the process you (essentially) flip a coin to choose one of two possibilities, and I don't see any step where that happens in your description. But sure, growing the population from N to N+N/2 by crossover and then reducing to N by selection is a reasonable thing to do.